# How running process does reload new lib file code dynamically in python?

Tags: python

I want to use  my project's new lib file. However, i don't hope to main progress stop running?
for example ,i have b.py:

```
import a
import time
def main():
    for i in range(1000):
        time.sleep(5)
        print i
        a.abc()
main()
```

a.py is

```
def abc():
    print 'abc'
```

I want to modify my `abc` function in a.py to

```
def abc():
    print '123'
```

When i finish modified `abc` function in a.py, I hope it worked at once in `main process` in a.py .
i remove a.pyc file, but it still **print abc, not 123**. How to print 123 when don't stop main progress?

**Can't change main process. Because it is always running.**

Answer (score 0):

You might want to save your module hashsum and after every execution check if it changed and reload if so:

```py
import hashlib
import time
import a


def main():
    with open('a.py', 'rb') as f:
        module_hashsum = hashlib.md5(f.read()).hexdigest()

    for i in range(1000):
        time.sleep(5)
        print i
        a.abc()

        with open('a.py', 'rb') as f:
            hashsum_temp = hashlib.md5(f.read()).hexdigest()

        if module_hashsum != hashsum_temp:
            module_hashsum = hashsum_temp
            reload(a)

main()
```

Or just reload it after every execution.

Might aswell do some fancy checks for file's `mtime`, like it's done in django. But it will trigger reload even if you didn't change anything in a file and only did :wq in Vim (just saved file) for e.g.
But I don't think it's necessary, as building hash is fast.

Comment: Note that `reload()` is no longer a builtin in python3 - and that reloading a module is actually not always trivial - you have to be very careful about imports (all client code must import the module and use qualified path - names locally imported with `from a import xxx` won't be affected by the reloading), and it will not work if your module defines classes and you have instances of those classes in your client code.

Comment: @Javed, I can't change main function. Because it is always running.

Comment: @PZY If you can't stop the script to make changes that will make reloading possible - there is absolutely no way for you to reload module dynamically.